# Is the following set open ot closed?

Tags: general-topology

$A=\left\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\mid  x^2+y^2<1\right\}$, $B=\left\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\mid (x-1)^2 + y^2 \leq 1\right\}$. $A$ is open. $B$ is closed. Is $A\cup B$ open? or semi open? In fact is there such a thing as semi open in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: I've edited your question, please make sure that this is what you intended. To answer your question, there is no such thing as semi open, it is not a topological concept.

Answer (score 5):

$A\cup B$ is not open and it is not closed.

- It is not open because the point $x_0 = (2,0)$ has no open neighborgood that is contained in $A\cup B$.
- It is not closed because the sequence $\{(-1 + \frac 1n, 0)\}_{n=1}^\infty$ of elements from $A\cup B$ has a limit but the limit is not in $A\cup B$

There is no such thing as "semi-open" in $\mathbb R^2$, as "semi-open" is a property of *intervals* in $\mathbb R$ with no easy generalization.